# Wordpress using index.php instead of archive.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My understanding from reading the [WP template hierachy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) was that when I set my a page as my posts page in `settings > reading settings` that Wordpress should use archive.php. Instead it uses `index.php`.

Obviously I could just put my code in `index.php` and my site will work. But it doesn't seem like best practice, and I can't find any documentation of best (or good) practice.

Why doesn't Wordpress use `archive.php` in this circumstance?

And would using `index.php` as my posts page have unintended consequences?

Note: I've been using the _s theme as a base, but I've had the same problem with no theme base or parent.

Comment: Did you set a specific page as your front page or a list of recent posts?

Comment: Yes, I always use a static front page. Does that have an impact?

Comment: Yes. archive.php is for listing the archives, not for a single entry. Use single.php (for posts) or page.php (for pages) or single-$posttype.php (for custom post types). You're looking for the Singular Page tree in the template hierarchy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you want to use **home.php** instead of archive.php as it is blog posts index page (set in WordPress Settings -> Reading). It is also in hierarchy on the third position from bottom.

Comment: Cool thanks, that kind of makes sense, because in old school wordpress your most recent posts would've been your home page.

Comment: Further to this you can see the template hierarchy visually [here](https://wphierarchy.com/). Look at **Blog Posts Index Page** as opposed to **Archive Page**.

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation for last 2/3 hours and by changing "Permalink Settings" to "post Name" in wordpress dashboard solved the problem for me.